# AWK Group by after n number of lines

Tags: unix, awk, sh

I have a text file like this:

```
lqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqwqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqwqqqqqqqqqqqqqk
xtable_name        xcolumn_name      xother_info   x
tqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqnqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqnqqqqqqqqqqqqqu
xqs_tab1           xcol01            xblahblah01   x
xqs_tab1           xcol02            xblahblah02   x
xqs_tab1           xcol03            xblahblah03   x
xqs_tab2           xcol09            xblahblah04   x
xqs_tab2           xcol01            xblahblah05   x
xqs_tab2           xcol02            xblahblah06   x
xqs_tab2           xcol03            xblahblah07   x
xqs_tab2           xcol04            xblahblah08   x
xqs_tab2           xcol05            xblahblah09   x
xqs_tab2           xcol06            xblahblah10   x
xqs_tab3           xcol01            xblahblah11   x
xqs_tab3           xcol02            xblahblah12   x
mqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqvqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqvqqqqqqqqqqqqqj
```

I would like to get a count of columns in each table like this:

```
qs_tab1, 3
qs_tab2, 7
qs_tab3, 2
```

Having read a similar question on this forum, I have created the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
awk '
BEGIN   { FS=" x";}
{
    tablename[$1]++;
}
END { for (i in tablename) {
        print tablename[i], i;
        }
}
'
```

This gets me most of the way there, however I would like to miss the first 3 rows and the last row.

I have tried putting `if (NR > 3)` type statements in various places, but I am always getting errors.

I would also like to avoid the first `"x"` in each row - however this is less of an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to put your condition(s) in front of the block of code that is adding to the array `tablename[]`:

```
#!/bin/sh
awk '
BEGIN   { FS=" x"; }
NR > 3 { tablename[$1]++; }
END { for (i in tablename) {
        print tablename[i], i;
        }
}
'
```

That will skip the first 3 lines. Skipping the last one isn't so simple though. To do this, we create a new variable to hold the value we are adding to the array until the next record. Then when we get to the last line the script ends and that last line doesn't ever hit the array. You can think of it like a buffer, which is often what I name this variable, here though I'll name it "firstfield" since it seems appropriate:

```
#!/bin/sh
awk '
BEGIN   { FS=" x" }
NR > 4 { tablename[firstfield]++ }
NR > 3 { firstfield=$1 }
END { for (i in tablename) {
        print tablename[i], i;
        }
}
'
```

Now we have that `firstfield` variable being set, but not being used until the next iteration/record/line for awk, effectively skipping the last line.